# $\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find an expression, in terms of $n$ and $a$, for $\int_{0}^{a}\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n}dx$. For what values of $n$ does $\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n}$ exist? State its value in terms of $n$. How to solve this question?

Comment: What happens if you substitute $u=1+x^2$?

Comment: I would observe that $xdx = \frac{1}{2} d \left( x^2 \right) $

Comment: You solve this question by using the most obvious substitution you can think of...

Comment: The case $n=1$ is special, since convergence fails for the integral to $\infty$. For the integral to $a$ we get a logarithm. For other positive integers $n$ we have convergence, and a simple formula after substituting $u=1+x^2$.

Comment: Whilst the integral can be evaluated in closed form, obviously we can see that for large $x$, the integrand is $O\left(x^{1-2n}\right)$.  Can you proceed now?

Answer (score 3):

Notice, let $1+x^2=t\implies 2xdx=dt$ $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n}\ dx=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^n}\frac{dt}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^n} dt$$  $$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{-n} dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle I_{n} = \int_{0}^{a}\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n}dx\;,$ Now put $1+x^2=t\;,$ Then $2xdx = dt$

So $$\displaystyle I_{n} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{1+a^2}\frac{1}{t^n}dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{1+a^2}t^{-n}dt = \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{t^{-n+1}}{-n+1}\right] = \frac{1}{2(1-n)}\left[(1+a^2)^{-n+1}-1\right]$$

Comment: Not quite true for $n=1$, but the discontinuity is removable by taking a limit as $n\to 1$.